# QGIS transparency as 4th input layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, transparency-opacity

I have a file that contains four rows. The first row indicates the longitude, the second row indicates the latitude, the third row indicates the colour of a specific longitude and latitude and the fourth row indicates the transparency of that specific location. I know how to input the first 3 layers and make it work, but I am unable to adjust the transparency of every single location. The data looks, for example, like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

### Quick 'almost' solution

Not exactly the solution you were looking for, but a close workaround: you can select color+transparency as a function of a field of your choice.

1. `Layer properties`
2. `Symbology`
3. Click on the menu icon to the right of `Fill color`
4. Select `Assistant`
5. Choose the field you want the transparency
6. Click on the `Reload` icon to calculate the range of that field
7. Click on the color ramp
8. Adjust the transparency of each Gradient Stop on the bottom chart.

[image: color-transparency by value]

### Complete solution

Play around with `color_rgba` in the field-based color

[image]

in the `Expression String Builder` field enter:

```
color_rgba(255,127,0, scale_linear("transp",0,1,0,255 ) )
```

[image]

If you need color and transparency, it should be possible to combine a color ramp into the expression.

Comment: This does not do what I need. I have 250k data points that belong in 8 different groups, but all 250k data points have a different transparency. Is it possible to link every data point to the transparency of the colour group it belongs to?

Comment: See if updated answer goes in the right direction

Comment: I think that might be what I need. But I'm unable to see the "single symbol" in "symbology" within the layer properties. When I upload the csv file with the four rows, I am only able to view the first three rows. I added the layer as a raster layer. How did you add the layer?

Comment: Import the `.csv` file as a Point feature via `Layers` -> `Add Delimited Text Layer`

Comment: A tutorial in case it is needed: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html